# Java File Appender write to windows network share

Tags: java

I am setting up the log4j logger in my code using a fileappender (see code below)

```
FileAppender qappender = new FileAppender();
qappender.setFile("C:\logfile1.txt");
```

How do I get it to write a file to a public windows network share like `\\server1\path1\path2\log.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Map the network share to a virtual drive such as `X:\path1\path2\log.txt` and then try writing.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [UNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention) path?

```
qappender.setFile("\\\\server\\share\\logfile1.txt")
```

(In Java string literals, `\\` is the escape sequence for the character `\`, so the above would write to the path `\\server\share\logfile1.txt` )

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an File, you can use an OutputStream opened from a URL which you can access files from the network.

```
URL url = new URL("file://server1/file.txt");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
```

Comment: He want to write the file, not read it. How do you write to a URL?

Comment: True. Sorry I miss on the answer but check it again.